# AVPlayerItemVideoOutput.copyPixelBuffer fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, runtime-error, allocation

I've that function:

```
func retrievePixelBufferToDraw() -> CVPixelBuffer? {
  let time = self.playerItem!.currentTime()

  // this line is just added to make sure I can call something on self.videoOutput!
  self.videoOutput!.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time)

  // raises EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  let pixelBuffer = self.videoOutput!.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time, itemTimeForDisplay: nil)
  return pixelBuffer
}
```

It sounds like `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` comes from accessing deallocated variables, but I don't really see how that'd come into play here since I've checked all the variables I'm using before calling the line that fails.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.. Your AVPlayer is not getting video input at same time it is throwing the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` Try to give it **QuickTimeMovie** when you are **playing** (`player.play()`) always require video input.

At the end `player` should not be `nill`(without proper `playerItem`)